# Blank section on the product list/scroller appearing instead of an item

Tags: css, wordpress, product

I have created a products list. Set to 4 columns however when I added a the 5th product there now appears to be a blank section where an item was is now replaced with a blank section.
Is there a way we can fix it. I am unsure how to get to this section as I believe there is a code that is causing this.

I went to inspect the blank page and found that removing the following element removes the blank section and it works as normal. However I myself have no idea how to get to this part in wordpress to remove it myself.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet or an image to help provide more context?

Comment: Heya  I would love to help, but it's hard to get an understanding of your problem with the information available. I'd suggest checking out [How do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the segment on [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Any links to your site, or examples of your code, images of intended and actual results. I hope I can help with more information!

Comment: oh yea good idea https://tradingcardnation.com.au if you click on inspect on the blank area it will show you the code. I tried to paste the code on the initial query but it wouldn't let me and I was not sure how to indent it.